# Performance of querying Apache Ignite using In-Clause

Tags: java, sql, caching, ignite

I have a schema created in Apache Ignite with 10 columns, where 3 of them are set index (say A, B are string type, C is int type). The total number of rows is around 40,000,000. Here is how I create cache table:

```java
CacheConfiguration<AffinityKey<Long>, Object> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
cacheCfg.setName(CACHE_NAME);
cacheCfg.setDataRegionName("MY_DATA_REGION");
cacheCfg.setBackups(1);

QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity(AffinityKey.class, Object.class)
        .setTableName("DataCache")
        .addQueryField("Field_A", String.class.getName(), null)
        .addQueryField("Field_B", String.class.getName(), null)
        .addQueryField("Field_C", Integer.class.getName(), null)
        .addQueryField("Field_D", Integer.class.getName(), null);

List<QueryIndex> queryIndices = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> groupIndices = new ArrayList<>();
groupIndices.add("Field_A");
groupIndices.add("Field_B");
groupIndices.add("Field_C");
queryIndices.add(new QueryIndex(groupIndices, QueryIndexType.SORTED));
queryEntity.setIndexes(queryIndices);
cacheCfg.setQueryEntities(Arrays.asList(queryEntity));
ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

I'm trying to query the ignite cache with sql statement like

```sql
select * from DataCache where 
Field_A in (...) and Field_B in (...) and Field_C in (...)
```

with each in-clause having 1000~5000 length. The querying speed is not fast, even slower than directly query to Google Big Query. I just wonder if there's any way to improve the query performance when using in-clause sql.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you created your table, but I'm guessing you have three indexes, one on each column. I suspect you'll need to create a [group index](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/SQL/indexes#group-indexes), i.e., one index across all three columns. With so many elements in your IN clauses, it may also be beneficial to rewrite as a JOIN.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I edit the above question by adding the method I create cache table. When I tried to create a group index like above, I didn't see the improvement, did I miss some configurations about group index?